# Passing array from form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following HTML form I am submitting to Django using post:

```
input id="array" type="text" class="arrayinput" name="array[]" placeholder="Thing 1">
input id="array" type="text" class="arrayinput" name="array[]" placeholder="Thing 2">
input id="array" type="text" class="arrayinput" name="array[]" placeholder="Thing 3">
```

And in the model of this form I have:

```
array = ListCharField(max_length=255, base_field=CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True))
```

However when I submit this array, it tells me that the form is missing the field array.

I assume this is because the field is called `array[]` but obviously I cannot name a python variable this. On the other hand, I cannot find any way to make a HTML array that has the functionality I need.

Comment: Why are they an array in the first place if they aren't part of the same input?

Comment: @Sayse we needed a way to join an unlimited number of text input boxes into the same input/variable (so theres an unlimted number of these arrayinputs that you can create on the site with a button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the field is called `array`, then just use that name in the HTML. There's no reason to add that pointless `[]`.

Comment: And this is why I hate working with HTML. Thank you :)